# Suppress warning "-std=c99 is not for C++"?

Tags: gcc, g++, compiler-warnings, suppress-warnings

I use [Orwell Dev-C++ IDE](https://sourceforge.net/projects/orwelldevcpp/) as my working environment. As a student and indie developer, I write both C codes and C++ codes, so I added this into "Compiler Options" settings

```
-std=c11 -std=c++17 -Wall -Wextra -s
```

Dev-C++ calls `gcc.exe` and `g++.exe` depending on file extension, so I can't create separate compiler profiles for C and C++. Then whenever I compile a program, either compiler says

```
[Warning] command line option '-std=c11' is valid for C/ObjC but not for C++
[Warning] command line option '-std=c++17' is valid for C++ but not for C
```

I am completely sure that it's safe to ignore this specific warning, but I'd like to suppress it. Is there anything I can supply to `gcc`/`g++` so it doesn't generate this warning?

In case it depends, I use MinGW GCC/G++ 6.3.0.

Comment: You cannot supress the warning. You can move away from Dev-C++.

Comment: Can you specify `gcc -std=c11` as the name of the C compiler instead of plain `gcc`?

Comment: @MarcGlisse Good idea and hopefully it worked!